# pie chart does not view although I use Table is working

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to view Pie chart with JSON format data when I am trying to use Table chart is working fine

I think the problem is parsing the JSON but I do not know where it is exactly

I also checked questions on this topic but not using it just like that they are using PHP as server-side but not like that on the HTML Page with javascript

That is the code

```
<html>   
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.charts.load('current', {
       callback: drawChart,
        packages:['table']
      });

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = [
    {"Car":23,"Bus":2,"Motorcycle":10,"Person":7},
    {"Car":5,"Bus":6,"Motorcycle":9,"Person":8},
    {"Car":10,"Bus":20,"Motorcycle":36,"Person":13}
  ];

  var gglData = [];
  if (jsonData.length > 0) {
    // load column headings
    var colHead = [];
    Object.keys(jsonData[0]).forEach(function (key) {
      colHead.push(key);
    });
    gglData.push(colHead);

    // load data rows
    jsonData.forEach(function (row) {
      var gglRow = [];
      Object.keys(row).forEach(function (key) {
        gglRow.push(row[key]);
      });
      gglData.push(gglRow);
    });
  }


  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(gglData);
  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
  table.draw(data);
  }
</script>
    </head>        
<body>
<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="table_div"></div>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you have to include package --> `'corechart'`

next, check the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#data-format) for a pie chart,
the data needs to be in rows vs columns...

see following working snippet,
each key / value pair is added as a separate row,
then the `group()` method is used to aggregate...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart', 'table']
});

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = [
    {"Car":23,"Bus":2,"Motorcycle":10,"Person":7},
    {"Car":5,"Bus":6,"Motorcycle":9,"Person":8},
    {"Car":10,"Bus":20,"Motorcycle":36,"Person":13}
  ];

  var gglData = [['Vehicle', 'Value']];
  jsonData.forEach(function (row) {
    Object.keys(row).forEach(function (key) {
      gglData.push([key, row[key]]);
    });
  });
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(gglData);

  var groupData = google.visualization.data.group(
    data,
    [0],
    [{column: 1, aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum, type: 'number'}]
  );

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(groupData);
  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
  table.draw(groupData);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```